# iPad smartcover repeats notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I've build an iPhone app and iPad users are experiencing a couple of problems with it, 
one is the following:

Notifications get repeated when a smartcover is attached to the iPad.
I'm simply scheduling a local notification for let's say 10.15:

```
 NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
            [comps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
            [comps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
            [comps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
            [comps setHour:10];
            [comps setMinute:15];
            NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
            NSDate *fireDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
            UILocalNotification *alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            alarm.fireDate = [fireDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeAdjustment];
            alarm.soundName = @"sounder.aiff";
            alarm.alertBody = @"Testing..";
            alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
               if ([alarm.fireDate compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedDescending) {[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];}
```

The notification goes off at the right time, but when an user closes their smartcase after the notification and opens the case again the iPad makes the notification repeat at let's say 10.59.
This is not what I want, It shall not repeat but I'm unsure where I can disable this in